# Step by step explanation of answer for discriminant function

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, prior, discriminant-analysis, decision-boundary

This is a question/answer from my first assignment (intro class on pattern recognition)

I don't understand how they used the p(x given w1) and p(x given w2) in the discriminant function. For example, how did they used the mean vector [0,0] and [d, e] in g(x)?

Can someone explain the missing steps from the original function to the simplified one?

QUESTION:

[image: Imgur]

ANSWER:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and detail why you cannot follow the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed the result so let me give you a few tips:

First of all, you want to know which values for $\boldsymbol{x}$ are possible in the boundary. The boundary should satisfy $g_1(\boldsymbol{x}) = g_2(\boldsymbol{x})$, so this is equivalent to:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_1 & x_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & c \\
 c & b \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & c \\
 c & b \\
\end{array}
\right|
+\frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_1-d & x_2-e \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1-d \\
 x_2-e \\
\end{array}
\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left| 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right|=0$$

where $\log\left|\Sigma\right|$ means the logarithm of the determinant $|\Sigma|$. Here you basically need to follow the usual rules of matrix multiplication. Notice that the second $\log$ will be $0$.

After you have performed the previous multiplications, remember to use the condition you're given: $a\times b-c^2=1$. This will be helpful (repeatedly) to simplify the previous expression. In fact, you can see that the first $\log$ can also be removed from the expression immediately.

I hope that helps.